# Count number of column value repeats in a pandas time window

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this dataset where accesses to a web server is sorted based on datetime, and the IPs of clients.
I want to know how many times a unique client has accessed the server during a specified time period, for example 10 seconds.

| Datetime | IP |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 207.213.193.143 |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 20.92.247.170 |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 207.213.193.143 |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 20.92.247.170 |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 207.213.193.143 |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 76.212.164.3 |

And what I want is something like this:

| Datetime | IP | Occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 207.213.193.143 | 1 |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 20.92.247.170 | 1 |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 207.213.193.143 | 2 |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 20.92.247.170 | 2 |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 207.213.193.143 | 3 |
| 2021-05-12 05:06:00 | 76.212.164.3 | 1 |

The solution I came up with was:

```
df['IP'] = df['IP'].astype('category')
df['Occurrences'] = df['IP'].cat.codes.rolling('10s').count()
```

But it gives me the count of all the elements during the time window.
How can I achieve the described behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) on `IP` and [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with a freq of 10s:

```
df['Occurrences'] = (
        df.groupby(
            ['IP', pd.Grouper(key='Datetime', freq='10s')]
        ).cumcount() + 1
)
```

`df`:

```
             Datetime               IP  Occurrences
0 2021-05-12 05:06:00  207.213.193.143            1
1 2021-05-12 05:06:00    20.92.247.170            1
2 2021-05-12 05:06:00  207.213.193.143            2
3 2021-05-12 05:06:00    20.92.247.170            2
4 2021-05-12 05:06:00  207.213.193.143            3
5 2021-05-12 05:06:00     76.212.164.3            1
```